# Parsing w/ case-sensitive text/tags

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm parsing through text using beautifulsoup and want to return the tags below/under a parent tag. However, between three different documents there exist inconsistencies between how the 'desired data set' is capitalized. See below:

```
<td class="pl "...-unimportant bits of script here-...;>Desired Data Set...</td>
```

and

```
<td class="pl "...-unimportant bits of script here-...;>Desired data set...</td>
```

and

```
<td class="pl "...-unimportant bits of script here-...;>desired data set...</td>
```

This is my code thus far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')

filenames = ['Desired Data Set','desired data set','Desired data set']

for filename in filenames:
    for item in soup.select('filename:contains("' + filename + '")'):
                    for td in item.find('td', text=filename).parent.find_all('td'):
                        data = [td.text.strip()]
                        print(data)
```

...and it works.

However, as I start to work with larger data sets, I'm sure there will be even more inconsistencies, and even though the above approach works it's 'hacky' and isn't efficient or prudent. I would like to just use one Filename for all desired data sets.

I've tried to lower the entire soup using lower() but it throws a NoneType error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text.lower(), 'lxml')` might be a 'hacky' way of solving the problem, but for my specific example it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string` argument of `find_all()` method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<table><tr><td class="pl ">Desired Data Set...</td>
<td class="pl ">Desired data set...</td>
<td class="pl ">desired data set...</td>
<td class="pl ">Something else</td>
</tr></table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for td in soup.find_all('td', string=lambda t: 'desired data set' in t.lower()):
    print(td)
```

Prints:

```
<td class="pl">Desired Data Set...</td>
<td class="pl">Desired data set...</td>
<td class="pl">desired data set...</td>
```

Comment: I'm needing to keep the general form of code in the OP for use parsing many different soups. The `for td in item.find('td', text=filename).parent.find_all('td')` bit is needed in some way shape or form. That said, how can I use the below code's structure and implement your recommendation? I keep having `NoneType` errors thrown anywhere I try to implement your code.